# UIImage+AFNetworking doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I have an image link, now i want to load this image in my app and i using category

```
[test setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"close"]];
```

link image is:

```
close
```

i see that link image is quite ok, but imageview can not load the image. Please tell me why, thanks!

Comment: test is an valid imageview ? outlet connected?

Comment: @NitinGohel : It is fine to use this extension

Comment: means what are you saying not getting you sir..

Comment: i test other link image is quite ok, but this link is not ok,

Comment: well there may be some issue with image while setting,make the same image upload to some other path and try to get it set

Comment: https://github.com/Amar11s/ASImageView  uiimageview category with placeholder and caching

Answer (score 1):

ok try this

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://216.57.222.146:8080/Stafflink_Web/images/assets/5108029/5108029_0_resized.jpg"];

            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
                         test.image = image;
                     }
                 });
             }
        });
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not method i want, you know that afnetworking or SDwebimage give us cache image, and load good for tableview cell

Answer (score 1):

Is `test` a UIImageView object? It needs to be.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```